# C++: Converting a double to an int without truncation

Tags: c++

For instance If i wanted to convert 4.234 into 4234 essentially removing the period. This far I have tried a mathematical solution because i don't want to do tedious conversions into char arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double convert(double numb)
{

    while(   (fmod(numb, 2.0) > 0.0)   &&   (fmod(numb, 2.0) != 1.0)   )
        numb = numb * 10;

    return numb;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << convert(60.49999) << "\n"; //doesn't work
    std::cout << convert(4.3); //works
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: This seems to work pretty well. Comments?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double convert(double numb)
{

    while(   (fmod(numb, 2.0) > 0.0)   &&   !(fmod(numb, 2.0) < 1.0)   )
        numb = numb * 10;

    return numb;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << convert(60.49999) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert(4.3); 
    return 0;
}
```

edit 2: My second solution does not work on the input 608.99

Comment: `fmod(numb, 2.0) != 1.0` This is not going to work well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ care to explain?

Comment: Convert it to a long instead and multiply by 10 to the exponent of however many digits the decimal needs to move to the right so in your case its 3. `10^3=1000, 4.234 * 1000 = 4234`

Comment: @Mike But how would I get that to work with all inputs?

Comment: I would say that the "tedious conversion into char arrays" - or, better, a `stringstream` - will be the way to go.   `4.3` cannot be exactly represented using a floating point variable, so it is probably blind luck -  or properties of the output stream that `std::cout << convert(4.3)` works at all.

Comment: you could try multiplying the number by 10 at a time and checking the number every time to see if its an integer inside a loop

Comment: @Mike haha. that was my first approach posted above.

Comment: This won't work, ever. [Read this](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: What if the double is greater than any value representable by int?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description. Your code does what I would expect it to do.  You should say what you expected to happen, and also say what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

First Convert number to String. Than remove dot from string and again convert string to Integer.
Hop this will help.

or If you wanna go by mathematical approach only than simply multiply number by 10 till it reaches its Integer Range and than check mode by 10 value if its 0 then do devide by 10 or else remain number is your answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

double convert(double numb)
{
    int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    while ((numb*10) <= imax)
        numb = numb * 10;

    int num = numb;
    while ((num%10) == 0)
        num = num / 10;

    return num;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << convert(4.233999999999) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert(4.234) << "\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or If you wanna go by mathematical approach only than simply multiply number by 10 till it reaches its Integer Range and than check mode by 10 value if its 0 then do devide by 10 or else remain number is your answer.

Comment: How do you check if "reaches integer range" ? Because `4.234` == `4.23399999996` and they both have to "reach integer range" at the same time.

Comment: In c++ under #include <limits>

Comment: That gives me a _lot_ of functions. Can you edit in the actual code ? Also, can you include the 2 examples `4.234` and `4.23399999996` ?

Comment: In c++ under this library
#include <limits>
there is a function like this std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
using this u have to check while multiplying number by 10 that it should be less than that number.

so for 4.234 u will get value like this 42340000
n for 4.23399999996 u will get value like this 42339999

and remaing thing is to remove tailng zero. which u can do easily by mod and divide by 10.

so for 4.234 u will get 4234 as your answer and 
 for 4.23399999996 u will get 42339999 as your answer. which is expected.

Comment: Well there's the problem: that doesn't work. Since computers store floating point numbers in binary, decimal `4.234` probably won't give you 4234000000.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

double convert(double numb)
{
 int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
 while ((numb*10) <= imax)
  numb = numb * 10;
 
 int num = numb;
 while ((num%10) == 0)
  num = num / 10;
    
    return num;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << convert(4.2339999) << "\n";
    std::cout << convert(4.234) << "\n"; 
    return 0;
}
I have excute the code. and its working.

Comment: [Doesn't work for 609.01](http://ideone.com/QCbDUP). It prints "6.0901e+08" instead of "60901".

Comment: works for GNU GCC v4.8.3 compiler. for me its working perfectly